# Do companies with an online store sometimes have two websites?

Tags: woocommerce, dns, e-commerce, online-store

I am trying to understand how some websites add the text ".store." before their domain when someone visits an online store side of their website. Usually this happens in cases where ecommerce is just a small part of a company's business.

Do companies like these have two websites? One having domain "www.business.com" and another "www.store.business.com"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a distinction between **domain** and **website**.

Following your question *business.com* would be the domain. It is usually bough and registered with a *registrar*. Maybe you've heard of some, like [NameCheap](https://www.namecheap.com/), [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com) or [Google Domains](https://domains.google/).

Now, usually these registrars will let you create DNS (Domain Name Server) rules (records) that allow requests directed to your domain to reach your server(s), which in turn will respond with whatever was requested (a *website*, for example). You can look at these DNS rules as a kind of "phone book" that associates the URL you type in your browsers search bar with the address of the server that will take care of your request.

There are many types of DNS rules, but suffice to say that you can also add **subdomains** to them, i. e., the parts that come *before* your domain in the URL. *www*, for instance, is already a subdomain of *business.com* in *www.business.com*, albeit a very frequently used one.

Long story short, yes, companies can have multiple websites. They are just computers that will respond to your requests differently (one will give you the company's corporate website while another will respond with its e-commerce one). The DNS records are the ones that will direct those requests to the right servers, and these records can reference subdomains, all based on the same main domain. The company only really needs to own the domain; it's up to them to add subdomains to it and point them to a different server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and informative answer.

Now I just need to figure out if it's worth it to create a multisite wordpress installation for this kind of purpose. Also, if there is any pros or cons to separating the online store side to it's own subdomain (?).